# How to overwrite website files with minimal downtime

Tags: backup, apache-http-server

I have a web server running on AWS, and I have spun up a *beta* instance so I can do some cleanup without affecting the live website.

Now I have tested and know it works fine, it is time to replace the sites. I do not want to switch the DNS as there a few things tied to the IP address and not just the domain name.

I had thought of creating a Directory and switching the Apache location to point there, then do a little housekeeping before pointing back.

What is the best way for me to do this? Apache directory change? Or is there a command line tool I can use to unzip a file into memory then overwrite a whole directory?

The Apache way seems like the best fit -- however, I am open to whatever options are out there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the directory change by editing the Apache config file to specify a new directory and then signalling Apache to reload it's configuration (e.g. [`apachectl graceful`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html) or SIGHUP etc). This won't disrupt existing transactions.

You can then clean up the old directories after allowing enough time for existing connections to be closed by the client ends.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do, but I was just checking if there was a utility tool sys admins may use to get this done? Otherwise I will do it the Apache way